# Detect or create tags in paragraph text with javascript in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, tags

In my Rails app, users type notes in a textarea, and need to create or select tags in the middle of text sometimes.

Example:
The quick brown fox jumps over the `#lazy` fox.

When the user starts typing, it should suggest tags, but if none exist, hitting space should create it.

I've created autocomplete APIs before, but I'm wondering if there's a javascript tag library that is designed for this use case, or whether it's something I will just have to create.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DUI%2FAutocomplete%26redirect%3Dno). This is the library stackoverflow used to use.

Comment: I looked at this, but couldn't tell--does it support the inline tag surrounded by non-tag text use case easily?

Comment: Yes, you would need to use regex to check every word against the tag list.